Why does the sum of different categories not add up to the total sum?
This might be a ridiculously stupid question, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this for some reason.
Let's say we have a store where we sold apples in 2023 and in 2024. Our sales have increased in 2024, but we sold a lower rate of apples relative to how many we had. We want to know how many apples we could have sold in 2024, if we had sold at the same rate as we did in 2023.

Why is it that when we take the total 2023 % sold of 95% and apply it to the 2024 Inventory, we get 1895 sold, but when we take each individual stores % sold and apply those to the 2024 Inventory, we get 1875 instead (500+500+500+375). And second question would be, which is the right method to use, the total values (1895) or summing up each individual store (1875)?

Because the two averages have different weightings.
To strip it down to its bare essentials: Suppose you have just two stores, which in $2023$ had inventories of $100$ and $200$, and suppose they sold $80$ and $120$, respectively, so the stores sold $4/5$ and $3/5$ of their inventory. The proportion of the total sold is $200$ of $300$, or $2/3$. Notice that $2/3$ is not the average of $4/5$ and $3/5$.
In $2024$, the two stores have inventories of $200$ and $250$, respectively. If the total sales rate were the same, the two stores would combine to sell $2/3$ of $200+250$, or $300$. But if each store individually sells at the same rate it did in $2023$, they would sell $160+150$, or $310$.

We can show this generally for two stores, with inventories $a_0$ and $b_0$ in year $0$, who sell at rates $p$ and $q$, respectively. The total sales in year $0$ are
$$
N_0 = a_0p+b_0q
$$
and so the proportion sold in year $0$ is
$$
r = \frac{a_0p+b_0q}{a_0+b_0}
$$
In year $1$, their inventories change to $a_1$ and $b_1$. If they each sell individually at their year $0$ rates, then the total sales would be
$$
N_1(\text{per-store}) = a_1p+b_1q
$$
But if they sell at their aggregate rates from year $0$, the total sales would be
$$
N_1(\text{aggregate}) = (a_1+b_1)r = \frac{a_1+b_1}{a_0+b_0}(a_0p+b_0q)
$$
In general, those two estimates are not the same. They are only the same when
$$
a_0b_1q + a_1b_0p = a_0b_1p + a_1b_0q
$$
or equivalently, when either $p = q$ or $b_1/a_1 = b_0/a_0$. For example, the difference in $2024$ disappears from the above example if we set either the $2023$ per-store sales to the same proportion of their inventories, or make their $2024$ inventories in the same $2$-to-$1$ ratio. The latter gives the average the same weighting in both years, while the former gives the average of two identical values, so the weighting doesn't matter.
A different expression would govern the situation for four stores. It would be more complicated. There might be a few different ways the averages could come out the same. But the basic principle would be the same.
